# Inverse diagonal on matrix

Tags: r, matrix

So I have 2 `dataframes`. picture them like so:

```
 data1 <- data.frame(c(1.2, 1.4, 1.3),
                     c(1.12,1.1, 1.9),
                     c(1.8, 1.1, 1.32))

 data2 <- data.frame(c(0.4, 0.2, 0.3),
                     c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4),
                     c(0.5, 0.7, 0.4))
```

how can I create a joint matrix that will look like this:

```
combined.data
> 1.2  1.12  1.80
  1.4 1.10  0.7
  1.3  0.4  0.4
```

upper left matrix is `data1`, lower-right is `data2`. I'm

So far, my code is this and I get what I want but up-side down:

```
new <- -data1
#new <- new[, rev(colnames(data1))]
# diag(new) <- NA
corel <- data2
#corel <- corel[, rev(colnames(data2))]


new[upper.tri(new)] <-  corel[upper.tri(corel)]
```

And I need the rows and column order to be intact

Any thoughts?

After using Haboryme's take, I somehow got the results. And I've generated a heatmap to show it. Problem is that in some spaces, the data are overlapping the 2 matrices.

Here's the heatmap
[image]

Above the diagonal it needs to be fully red, and below the diagonal, blue.

I've accepted the answer by Haboryme. and the problem was that my data was 32*31. if your matrix **is not** square it's going to be a mess! 
I just added 1 dummy column to my dataset and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Your lines give warnings and what they produce is very unlikely to be what you had in mind. Please, spend some time to make sure that we have a reproducible example.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but first of all change `as.data.frame` to `data.frame`. I have a feeling the problem might lie in that you think that each vector of numbers you are reading into the data frame is a row whereas it is actually a column i.e `c(1.2, 1.4, 1.3)` produces the first COLUMN of `data1`.

Comment: Maybe they want `rbind` instead of `as.data.frame`...

Comment: @Frost_Maggot check now, I fixed it

Comment: @nicola I've run it again. I don't get any errors... 
Check again the desired output. I changed it to what I want it to be

Comment: Are your matrices square and of equal "dim"? You could try subsetting and assigning with `row(data2) > col(data2)[, ncol(data2):1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
data1 <- data.frame(c(1.2, 1.4, 1.3),
                    c(1.12,1.1, 1.9),
                    c(1.8, 1.1, 1.32))

data2 <- data.frame(c(0.4, 0.2, 0.3),
                    c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4),
                    c(0.5, 0.7, 0.4))

combined=as.matrix(data1)
combined[apply(lower.tri( as.matrix(data2)), 1, rev)]  <-as.matrix(data2)[apply(lower.tri( as.matrix(data2)), 1, rev)]

> combined
     c.1.2..1.4..1.3. c.1.12..1.1..1.9. c.1.8..1.1..1.32.
[1,]              1.2              1.12               1.8
[2,]              1.4              1.10               0.7
[3,]              1.3              0.40               0.4
```

Comment: I just gave a go in to your approach. It works kinda... problem is that at some points one matrix is overlapping with the other. How can I add a picture of a heatmap to show you how it behaves?

Comment: check now please.

Comment: @Mixalis could you provide data that leads to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's exactly like example I gave you, only in 2 `32*31` matrices. What if we substitute the removed parts of the matrices with `NA`?

Comment: @Mixalis 32*31? if they are not square it's not going to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134804/discussion-between-mixalis-and-haboryme).